# Running WPF browser application in Web Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, browser, settings

I want to set in whitch browser will run my WPF browser app. Is it possible? If will I click Debug button, it will start my app in google chrome, but I want to run it in IE, because in Google Chrome i have not xpcom.dll.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: First, Are you sure you created a WPF application, because there is no way to run it inside browser. I think you created Silverlight application. Second, your visual studio runs google chrome because it's your default browser. Third, Please make your question clear.

Comment: I had maked WPF browser application. Look on EDIT.

Comment: But I don't want to make Google Chrome as my default browser. I have asked if is it possible configure it in Visual Studio.

Comment: you don't need to vote down my post, my friend. we don't play a game here, we want to share something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would normally do that by setting the start action. Right click on the start up project in the solution explorer and select properties. Go to the debug tab and under start action there should be an option to start an external program where you could choose your preferred browser and set up the command line arguments appropriately.

Trouble is, I've got a feeling this is only available in the full versions of visual studio...maybe you're using an express edition?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that, I searched Visual Studio configuration, there is no way to set any browser as default visual studio browser. But, if it's very important for you to browse it in specific browser you can switch default browser application inside your project app.cs file. have a look at this links, I hope it will help you understand how to change it in your code **[For WPF Application Only]**, I looked project properties in solution explorer, you can go to debug tab inside Start Action select Start external program select IE executable file, then under Start Option inside the command line argument clear `-Debug` then start your application you will see it runs inside IE and will download **YOUR_APP_NAME.xbap** file.

[How do i change default browser using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968449/how-do-i-change-default-browser-using-c-or-batch-file)

Comment: for what will i need change default browser in C#, when I cannot start application?