# Set application as default browser

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I need to set my application as a default web browser for "**HTTP**" and "**HTTPS**" protocols. And I need to do it from application. My app is in C# using .Net 3.5. (It is a web browser)

Answer (score 1):

The default browser is set in the Windows registry and I would presume that the "command" in the link below would be your application.
See here: [How do I change default browser using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968449/how-do-i-change-default-browser-using-c-sharp-or-batch-file)

Comment: From these answers no-one works ...