# How can I open my vb.net application when an http/https link is launched?

Tags: .net, vb.net, hyperlink, file-association

I've spent a great deal of time researching file associations in vb.net and found over a dozen tutorials on opening the default program for a file type or link through vb.net, but nothing in regards to opening your vb.net application as the default application for files and links.

**I want** my vb.net application **(that contains a webbrowser component)** *to open as the default web browser* when a http/https link is clicked from another app or from a shortcut, then to **navigate to said link in my applications webbrowser control.**

**I do not want** my application *to open another browser application* to open the desired link. This is not helpful as my application is intended to be used as a web browser.

This is not a duplicate of [how do i change default browser using c# or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968449/how-do-i-change-default-browser-using-c-sharp-or-batch-file) because that only answers part of my question. I still cant navigate to the link that opened my application in my webbrowser component.

If anyone has any examples of how to accomplish this please share them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i change default browser using c# or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968449/how-do-i-change-default-browser-using-c-sharp-or-batch-file)

Comment: The link that opened your application is passed to your application as a command line parameter.